# How to get marker lat and long on flutter map?

Tags: flutter, leaflet

I'm using mapbox on flutter with flutter_map package and need to add marker on map when tapped on map and then get marker lat and long to send to server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, this functionality isn't available yet. There is however a pull request you can use to get this functionality while you wait for the Flutter team to merge it into the flutter_google_maps repo. [You can find the pull request and code here](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/1121)

When using this pull request version you can do something like the below:

```
void _onMapLongTapped(LatLng location) {
  // add place marker code here
  _addMyMarker(location);
}

Future<void> _addMyMarker(LatLng location) async {
if (_myMarker != null) {
  mapController.updateMarker(
    _myMarker,
    MarkerOptions(
        position: LatLng(
      location.latitude,
      location.longitude,
    )),
  );
} else {
  _myMarker = await mapController.addMarker(
    MarkerOptions(
      position: LatLng(
        location.latitude,
        location.longitude,
      ),
    ),
  );
}}
```